# Update script not working

Tags: php, mysql

This should be pretty simple but for some reason I can't get this value to update in my database. I've used a line of code on a different page that was nearly identical and it worked fine. The only differences are the if statement  and the WHERE statement.

```
if ($item_number == '9')

mysql_query("UPDATE authorize SET tokens= ( tokens +1 ) WHERE email= '$payer_email'");
```

Here is the entire script:

```
<?

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];
$settle_amount = $_POST['settle_amount'];
$memo = $_POST['memo'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
$option_name1 = $_POST['option_name1'];
$option_selection1 = $_POST['option_selection1'];
$option_name2 = $_POST['option_name2'];
$option_selection2 = $_POST['option_selection2'];
$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_business_name = $_POST['payer_business_name'];
$payer_id =$_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$exchange_rate = $_POST['exchange_rate'];
$settle_currency  = $_POST['settle_currency'];
$parent_txn_id  = $_POST['parent_txn_id'];
$pending_reason = $_POST['pending_reason'];
$reason_code = $_POST['reason_code'];


// subscription specific vars

$subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];
$subscr_date = $_POST['subscr_date'];
$subscr_effective  = $_POST['subscr_effective'];
$period1 = $_POST['period1'];
$period2 = $_POST['period2'];
$period3 = $_POST['period3'];
$amount1 = $_POST['amount1'];
$amount2 = $_POST['amount2'];
$amount3 = $_POST['amount3'];
$mc_amount1 = $_POST['mc_amount1'];
$mc_amount2 = $_POST['mc_amount2'];
$mc_amount3 = $_POST['mcamount3'];
$recurring = $_POST['recurring'];
$reattempt = $_POST['reattempt'];
$retry_at = $_POST['retry_at'];
$recur_times = $_POST['recur_times'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//auction specific vars

$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$auction_closing_date  = $_POST['auction_closing_date'];
$auction_multi_item  = $_POST['auction_multi_item'];
$auction_buyer_id  = $_POST['auction_buyer_id'];



//DB connect creds and email 
$notify_email =  "mail@mail.com";         //email address to which debug emails are     sent to
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "username"; //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "pass"; //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "dbname"; //your MySQL Database Name


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {



//create MySQL connection
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


//select database
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());


$fecha = date("m")."/".date("d")."/".date("Y");
$fecha = date("Y").date("m").date("d");

//check if transaction ID has been processed before
$checkquery = "select txnid from paypal_payment_info where txnid='".$txn_id."'";
$sihay = mysql_query($checkquery) or die("Duplicate txn id check query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
$nm = mysql_num_rows($sihay);
if ($nm == 0){

//execute query



if ($txn_type == "cart"){
$strQuery = "insert into     paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,    country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,dat    ecreation) values     ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_st    reet."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."',    '".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_i    d."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";

 $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Cart - paypal_payment_info, Query     failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++) {
     $itemname = "item_name".$i;
     $itemnumber = "item_number".$i;
     $on0 = "option_name1_".$i;
     $os0 = "option_selection1_".$i;
     $on1 = "option_name2_".$i;
     $os1 = "option_selection2_".$i;
     $quantity = "quantity".$i;

     $struery = "insert into     paypal_cart_info(txnid,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,invoice,custom) values     ('".$txn_id."','".$_POST[$itemnumber]."','".$_POST[$itemname]."','".$_POST[$on0]."','".$_PO    ST[$os0]."','".$_POST[$on1]."','".$_POST[$os1]."','".$_POST[$quantity]."','".$invoice."','"    .$custom."')";
     $result = mysql_query($struery) or die("Cart - paypal_cart_info, Query     failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

 }
}



else{
 $strQuery = "insert into     paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,    country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,payme    ntdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_st    reet."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."',    '".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$o    ption_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."    ','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_co    de."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
 $result = mysql_query("insert into     paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,    country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,payme    ntdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values     ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_st    reet."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."',    '".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$option_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."    ','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_co    de."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')") or die("Default - paypal_payment_info, Query     failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
}


// send an email in any case
 echo "Verified";
 mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n      $strQuery2");
}
else {
// send an email
mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED DUPLICATED TRANSACTION", "$res\n $req \n $strQuery\n     $struery\n  $strQuery2");
}

//subscription handling branch
if ( $txn_type == "subscr_signup"  ||  $txn_type == "subscr_payment"  ) {

  // insert subscriber payment info into paypal_payment_info table
  $strQuery = "insert into     paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,    country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,dat    ecreation) values     ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_st    reet."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."',    '".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_i    d."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";

$result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Subscription - paypal_payment_info, Query     failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

//This is where the problem is

if ($item_number == '9')

mysql_query("UPDATE authorize SET tokens= ( tokens +1 ) WHERE email= '$payer_email'");




     // insert subscriber info into paypal_subscription_info table
    $strQuery2 = "insert into paypal_subscription_info(subscr_id , sub_event,     subscr_date ,subscr_effective,period1,period2, period3, amount1 ,amount2 ,amount3,      mc_amount1,  mc_amount2,  mc_amount3, recurring, reattempt,retry_at, recur_times, username     ,password, payment_txn_id, subscriber_emailaddress, datecreation) values     ('".$subscr_id."',         '".$txn_type."','".$subscr_date."','".$subscr_effective."','".$period1."','".$period2."','"    .$period3."','".$amount1."','".$amount2."','".$amount3."','".$mc_amount1."','".$mc_amount2."','".$mc_amount3."','".$recurring."','".$reattempt."','".$retry_at."','".$recur_times."','    ".$username."','".$password."', '".$txn_id."','".$payer_email."','".$fecha."')";
    $result = mysql_query($strQuery2) or die("Subscription -     paypal_subscription_info,     Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


         mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n      $strQuery2");

}
}




// if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this


else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation

mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Any ideas as to why it wont update the value?

Comment: I don't even know enough PHP to know if it will do the string substitution as you are using it, but I do know it's a suicidally bad idea to use a raw string like that, as I hope you never find out [the hard way](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: You **really** should use parameterized SQL queries... your code is just *begging* for someone to inject SQL into it!

Comment: Are you sure about your string concatenation in your sql request?

Comment: I really need to research how sql injections work and how to prevent them before I launch my site. Right now I just want to make it functional.

Comment: @ jeremy, well I know that a very similar statement worked fine for me. The only things I changed were adding the if statement and using a different where statement.

Comment: make sure to check if the post variables are set. if(isset($_POST['item_name']) { $item_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);} else {....}    also make sure to escape and validate all the post variables. If possible check against a predefined array.

Comment: @user1206214 Using Parameterized SQL statements are very easy, make your code easier to read (no messy string concatenations!), *prevent* all SQL injections, and often *improve* performance! It is *extremely* hard to bolt on security after the fact, it always ends up biting people for putting it off!

Comment: check my answer and update me if I am missing anything...

Comment: What @Kitsune said.  When implementing, security is done first, optimization is done last.  Correctness, getting the thing to actually work, is in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the value of $item_number and return value of the mysql_query. 
Also check all that all the if conditions are properly closed.

Comment: I just tried that and it's still not updating, does it matter where in the script I put the if and where statement?

Comment: I figured it out, I guess my if statement was buried in another if statement or something. I moved it to the bottom of the script and it updated.Thanks for joggin my brain for me :)

Comment: Glad it helped...Please think about the comments for your question and also use proper indentations and braces which will make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

Isn't you query should be

`mysql_query("UPDATE authorize SET tokens= ( tokens +1 ) WHERE email= '" .$payer_email. "'");`